# Why is the javascript function not called in a web page?

Tags: .net

There are two textboxes  (txtTimeFrom and txtTimeTo)  for a time period in a webpage using a asp.net Master page. I used a javascript to validate the data a user enters in these two boxes as a date type on TxtTimeTo onBlur event then call TextTimeTo's code behind event TextChanged to  access SQL to get data.

The issues is the javascript is never called and TextChanged is fired directly. How to solve this issues? Thanks in advance!

<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/forms/Site.Master" CodeBehind="UniformEval.aspx.vb" Inherits="Eval2010.UniformEval" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>



        function checkEnteredDates(stdateval, endateval) {
            //seperate the year,month and day for the first date
            var stryear1 = stdateval.substring(6);
            var strmth1 = stdateval.substring(0, 2);
            var strday1 = stdateval.substring(5, 3);
            var date1 = new Date(stryear1, strmth1, strday1);

```
        //seperate the year,month and day for the second date
        var stryear2 = endateval.substring(6);
        var strmth2 = endateval.substring(0, 2);
        var strday2 = endateval.substring(5, 3);
        var date2 = new Date(stryear2, strmth2, strday2);

        var datediffval = (date2 - date1) / 864e5;

        if (datediffval <= 0) {
            alert("Start date must be prior to end date");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This function validates the date for MM/DD/YYYY format. 
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function isValidDate(dateStr) {

        // Checks for the following valid date formats:
        // MM/DD/YYYY
        // Also separates date into month, day, and year variables
        var datePat = /^(\d{2,2})(\/)(\d{2,2})\2(\d{4}|\d{4})$/;

        var matchArray = dateStr.match(datePat); // is the format ok?
        if (matchArray == null) {
            alert("Date for Date From or Date to must be in MM/DD/YYYY format")
            return false;
        }

        month = matchArray[1]; // parse date into variables
        day = matchArray[3];
        year = matchArray[4];
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) { // check month range
            alert("Month must be between 1 and 12");
            return false;
        }
        if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            alert("Day must be between 1 and 31");
            return false;
        }
        if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day == 31) {
            alert("Month " + month + " doesn't have 31 days!")
            return false;
        }
        if (month == 2) { // check for february 29th
            var isleap = (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
            if (day > 29 || (day == 29 && !isleap)) {
                alert("February " + year + " doesn't have " + day + " days!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;  // date is valid
    }
</script>
```

```
<tr>
    <td class="ForumsHeader">Rating Period: </td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;&nbspFrom&nbsp;<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calratingFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtratingFrom"></asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtratingFrom" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvratingFrom" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtratingFrom" Display="None" 
            ErrorMessage="Please select/enter Date for Rating From"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvratingFrom" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtratingFrom" ErrorMessage="Please select/enter right Date format for Rating From" 
            Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" Display="None"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvRatingFrom" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtratingFrom" Display="None" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter a right date range for RatingPeriod From!" 
            MaximumValue="01/01/2020" MinimumValue="01/01/2010" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="calratingTo" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtratingTo"></asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtratingTo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            onblur="javascript:ValidateRatingPeriod();" ></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvratingTo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtratingTo" ErrorMessage="Please select/enter Date for Rating To" 
        display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvratingTo" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtratingTo" ErrorMessage="Please select/enter right Date format for Rating To"
            Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date" Display="None"></asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvRatingTo" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtratingTo" Display="None" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter a right date range for RatingPeriod To!" 
            MaximumValue="01/01/2020" MinimumValue="01/01/2010" Type="Date"></asp:RangeValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
    <tr><td class="ForumsHeader" colspan="2"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td width="50%"><asp:button id="butSubmit" runat="server" Width="120px" CssClass="FormButtonBig" Text="Submit"></asp:button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code Behind for TextChanged event as follows

```
Protected Sub txtratingTo_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtratingTo.TextChanged
    Dim dt As DataTable

    If IsDate(txtratingTo.Text) And IsDate(txtratingFrom.Text) Then
        Try
            dt = Logic.GetUMOSSickInfo(lblTaxID.Text, txtratingFrom.Text, txtratingTo.Text)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                txtTimesSick.Text = dt.Rows(0)("NLODSickTimes").ToString()
                txtTimesSickLOD.Text = dt.Rows(0)("LODSickTimes").ToString()
                txtDaysLost.Text = dt.Rows(0)("NLODSickDays").ToString()
                txtDaysLostLOD.Text = dt.Rows(0)("LODSickDays").ToString()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Redirect("../errors/errorgeneric.aspx?error=" & ex.Message.ToString & "&EvalID=" & ViewState("EvalID") & "&ErrPage=ChronicStatus", False)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Posting some code would go a long way towards helping you find the answer. Without code, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your description, i guess you want to do the validations for two textboxes (both server side and client side) including the data type and one server call (not sure what that is).  I do the whole thing with javascript with little help from Ajax.  I do not think the event handler --TextChanged is a good solution.  It's only going to make your Viewstate bigger and bigger which degrades performance.

ASPX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Why is the javascript function not called in a web page?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=txtRatingFrom.ClientID%>').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                ,minDate: new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1)
                , maxDate: '+10Y'
                , changeMonth: true
                , changeYear: true
            });
            $('#<%=txtRatingTo.ClientID%>').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
                , minDate: new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1)
                , maxDate: '+10Y'
                , changeMonth: true
                , changeYear: true
            });
        });

        function form1_OnSubmit() {
            var isFormValid = true;
            if (isEitherDateMissing()) {
                alert('Dates are missing');
                isFormValid = false;
            } else if (!isFromDateBeforeToDate()) {
                alert('From Date is not before the to date');
                isFormValid = false;
            } else if (!isServerCallValid()) {
                alert('Server validation failed...');
                isFormValid = false;
            }
            isFormValid = false;
            alert('isFormValid: ' + isFormValid);
            return isFormValid;
        }

        function isEitherDateMissing() {
            var fromDate = $('#<%=txtRatingFrom.ClientID%>').val();
            var toDate = $('#<%=txtRatingTo.ClientID%>').val();
            var bIsEitherDateMissing = (fromDate == "") || (toDate == "") ? true : false;
            return bIsEitherDateMissing;
        }
        function isFromDateBeforeToDate() {  // pre condition: both inputs are dates
            var fromDate = new Date($('#<%=txtRatingFrom.ClientID%>').val());
            var toDate = new Date($('#<%=txtRatingTo.ClientID%>').val());
            var bIsFromDateBeforeToDate = (fromDate.getTime() < toDate.getTime()) ? true : false;
            return bIsFromDateBeforeToDate;
        }
        function isServerCallValid() {
            var param1 = "1", param2 = "1", param3 = "1";
            var bIsServerCallValid = true;
            $.ajax({
                cache: false
                , type: "POST"
                , url: "Test0.aspx/IsServerCallGood"
                , data: "{param1: '" + param1 + "'," +
                        "param2:'" + param2 + "'," +
                        "param3:'" + param3 + "'}"
                , contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
                , dataType: "json"
                , success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d != null) {
                        bIsServerCallValid = data.d;
                    }
                }
                , error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.toString);
                }
            })
            return bIsServerCallValid;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>Rating From
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRatingFrom" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
    </div>
    <div> Rating To 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRatingTo" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:return form1_OnSubmit();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class Test0 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool IsServerCallGood(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        bool bIsGood = false;
        // your business logic function call
        return bIsGood;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. What I want to get is use JavaScript to validate data entry for date type and then on code behind TextChanged event to get sick days based on these two dates and show them on the web page.

Comment: You  don't need the textchanged handler at call. It can be done with ajax.